# React routing to a page with dynamically determined slug

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am using React, Redux and React-router and would like to get the following use case to work:

- From the page that displays a list of entries (each entry has a unique id and a slug that is known)
- When you click on one entry you are taken to that entry's page
- The page is loaded dynamically - an ajax request is sent with the page's id and all the content is filled based on the request's output.

How can I create a url with each item's slug? Right now I just have a fixed

```
<Route path="/item" component={ItemPage} />
```

What I would want is

```
<Route path="/<slug>" component={ItemPage} />
```

where slug is only known once you navigate to the page from another page.

Another issue I have - all content of the page disappears upon refresh. This is caused by the fact that I pass the item id to the ItemPage via state, and the the id is no longer set in the state after a refresh.

Maybe more generally, what would be the way to implement the above behaviour? It seems like a common use case and I can't find a good reference on how to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this:

`<Route path="/:slug" component={ItemPage} />`

Check out [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) from the react-router docs on URL params.